# Access Query Build Wizard Form is Blank

Tags: ms-access

I am using Access 2010. When starting "Query Build Wizard", I will always see a form without any controls, as below:

[image]

Then even if I click "Cancel" or "Finish". Nothing happens. I will have to use Task Manager to terminate Access mandatory. Why?

Comment: Query builder pops up what appears to a be user-created form: *frui_frmMain*? Check this form for any automated code. You might have a corrupted database. Create a new .accdb file and import all objects from this one and destroy this version.

Comment: @Parfait, Sorry but I am using a new created database which is not corrupt. I even try to create another new database but still encounter such a problem.